# React application not working in Apache server on CentOS

Tags: reactjs, apache

I am facing issue to run the React application  on CentOS server with Apache server.
Can any one help me out to figure out this issue please.

**Apache Config:**

nano /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
    <VirtualHost *:8081>
     ServerName localhost
      DocumentRoot /root/CC_CRM/client/dist
     <Directory "/root/CC_CRM/client/dist">

    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    # Don't rewrite files or directories
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
    </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

Getting `Unable to connect` issue on browser.

Comment: do you have your React app running? there is some steps that you need to do before having the app running through apache, is just HTML or do you have it served through normal HTML file?

Comment: @mamounothman I buidl my react app and given the dist folder path in <Directory> in Apache config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Unable to connect error` is thrown when you server is refused to connect that means your server isn't running or if it's running it might be running on different port instead of `80`. 
To be sure you have to share you `apache` config file and after starting `apache` check for the `LISTENING` ports in `CentOs`
To run app on another port

1. Add additional ports in the `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` like so:

   Listen 80

   Listen 8888

Now in your `VirtualHost` file add that port like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *:8888>
....other configs here
</VirtualHost>
```

Restart apache2:

```
sudo apache2ctl restart
```

Comment: Yes you are correct. Apache running at 80 port so I Just trying to run the React application in different port. Kindly  guide me to do that same process please.